# Как разместить блоки друг за другом?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть код

Нужно разместить перед оранжевыми блоками еще одни блоки. Я понимаю, что возможно вопрос дилетантский, но все же.

```css
.our_work {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.bg {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 44%;
  min-width: 20px;
  min-height: 22px;
  height: 222px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.bg:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}
.blcok {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 42%;
  height: 50%;
}
.img_work {
  position: absolute;
}
.abs {
  right: 5%;
}
.abs1 {
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<section class="our_work">
  <div class="adler_work blcok">
    <p>текст примера</p>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <figure class="img_work">
      <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </figure>

    <div class="bg"></div>
    <figure class="img_work abs1">
      <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="novoros_work blcok">
    <p>текст примера</p>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <figure class="img_work">
      <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </figure>

    <div class="bg"></div>
    <figure class="img_work abs">
      <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="krd_work blcok">
    <p>текст примера</p>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <figure class="img_work">
      <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </figure>

    <div class="bg"></div>
    <figure class="img_work abs1">
      <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="tuapse_work blcok">
    <p>текст примера</p>
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <figure class="img_work">
      <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </figure>

    <div class="bg"></div>
    <figure class="img_work abs">
      <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

но надо сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните мне пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать такую возможность? Много всего уже пробовал...

Comment: а в чем проблема в расположении блоков? http://jsfiddle.net/qtn9un31/

Comment: @soledar10, вы не поняли, нужно перед оранжевыми блоками разместить..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vkpufL7a/ - так?

Comment: @soledar10 то что надо! благодарю! буду изучать) спасибо большое)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, не надо использовать задний блок. Вместо него следует применить box-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Cпасибо большое, @soledar10

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.works {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.works h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.list-works {
  text-align: center;
}
.list-works > li,
.works-item {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 46%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  position: relative;
}
.list-works > li {
  margin: 25px 2%;
}
.works-item img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  /* box-shadow: -10px -10px #FF9F18;*/
}
.img1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.works-item p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="works">
  <h2>WORKS</h2>
  <ul class="list-works">
    <li>
      <figure class="works-item">
        <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img1" />
        <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" alt="" class="img2" />
        <p>Before</p>
      </figure>
      <!--
         -->
      <figure class="works-item">
        <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img1" />
        <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" alt="" class="img2" />
        <p>After</p>
      </figure>

      <li>
        <figure class="works-item">
          <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img1" />
          <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" alt="" class="img2" />
          <p>Before</p>
        </figure>
        <!--
         -->
        <figure class="works-item">
          <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img1" />
          <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" alt="" class="img2" />
          <p>After</p>
        </figure>


        <li>
          <figure class="works-item">
            <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img1" />
            <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" alt="" class="img2" />
            <p>Before</p>
          </figure>
          <!--
         -->
          <figure class="works-item">
            <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img1" />
            <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img2" />
            <p>After</p>
          </figure>

          <li>
            <figure class="works-item">
              <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img1" />
              <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" alt="" class="img2" />
              <p>Before</p>
            </figure>
            <!--
         -->
            <figure class="works-item">
              <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" class="img1" />
              <img src="http://img.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/4/18002/18002743_crying_baby2.jpg" alt="" class="img2" />
              <p>After</p>
            </figure>
  </ul>

</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkpufL7a)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Athari, как не является, если то, что мне надо? или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: После исправления уже больше похоже на ответ. Но объяснений всё равно ноль.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью позиционирования и z-index(если понадобится), либо с помощью тени. Ответил "вообще", ведь ответы уже написаны)

Comment: Если пишете ответ, то пишите нормальный ответ с разбором и примерами, а не отписку в одну строчку. Тем более, если другие ответы содержательнее.